# bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install xampp giving an error bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Edit question and add the output of the command: `$ file xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run`

Comment: ... also `uname -m`